# How to generate key with RSA and aes-256-gcm?

Tags: openssl

I want to generate key with RSA and AES 256 GCM but I am getting following error every time:

```
$ openssl genpkey -out mkey.pem -aes-256-gcm -algorithm rsa
.........................++++++
..............++++++
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
Error writing key
140735190483024:error:0D0A7072:asn1 encoding routines:PKCS5_pbe2_set_iv:error setting cipher params:p5_pbev2.c:133:
140735190483024:error:2307D00D:PKCS12 routines:PKCS8_encrypt:ASN1 lib:p12_p8e.c:86:
```

When I try to use `aes-256-ctr` I also get error but slightly different:

```
$ openssl genpkey -out mkey.pem -aes-256-ctr -algorithm rsa
.................++++++
.....++++++
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
Error writing key
140735190483024:error:0D0A706C:asn1 encoding routines:PKCS5_pbe2_set_iv:cipher has no object identifier:p5_pbev2.c:104:
140735190483024:error:2307D00D:PKCS12 routines:PKCS8_encrypt:ASN1 lib:p12_p8e.c:86:
```

OpenSSL version `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`. Max OS X 10.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL doesn't support that.

From https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/genpkey.html:

```
-cipher
    This option encrypts the private key with the supplied cipher. Any algorithm name
    accepted by EVP_get_cipherbyname() is acceptable such as des3.
```

From https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html:

```
The enc program does not support authenticated encryption modes like CCM and GCM.
The utility does not store or retrieve the authentication tag.
```

You can find the list of ciphers you can specify under the "SUPPORTED CIPHERS" section of `enc.html`:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html#SUPPORTED-CIPHERS

Comment: So what can I do? Are there other libraries? My project has a requirement to use aes-256-gcm to generate key(s) that will be used to encrypt some data...

Comment: I think it depends on what you're really trying to do. Are you looking for an existing standalone utility that does AES-GCM encryption? I'm not aware of one. If you're going to integrate a crypto library into your project, then you can use OpenSSL for AES-GCM. Note that the cipher you're choosing here is only being used to encrypt the private key (and I see no particularly compelling reason for a private key to be encrypted using AES-GCM). It has nothing to do with what kind of encryption you can do with this key on other data.